# How do i make my hover caption to cover the whole image size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, caption

I'm trying to make a hover caption that adapts itself to the full image width and height even when it resizes. I've tried using a jquery code that I found here but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgWidth = $('.imagen').width();
    $('.caption-text').css({width: imgWidth});
  $('.caption-style-1').css({width: imgWidth});
  $('.blur').css({width: imgWidth});
});
```

```css
.container-a1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.caption-style-1{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
 }

 .caption-style-1 li{
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .caption-style-1 li:hover .caption{
  opacity: 1;

 }


 .caption-style-1 img{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
 }


 .caption-style-1 .caption{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;

 }
 .caption-style-1 .blur{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
 }

 .caption-style-1 .caption-text h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
 }
 .caption-style-1 .caption-text{
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  top:100px;
 }

.imagen {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-a1">
  <ul class="caption-style-1">
   <li>
    <img class="imagen" src="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/claude-monet/the-summer-poppy-field.jpg"/" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
     <div class="blur"></div>
     <div class="caption-text">
      <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
      <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: But it is already adapting to the full height and width of the image. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz3ywc1o/)

Comment: I made a snippet to show you :)

Comment: Look at my answer. I think is what you are looking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then, you just have to also add the `height` property of your `image` to your `.blur` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgWidth = $('.imagen').width();
    var imgHeight = $('.imagen').height();
    $('.caption-text').css({width: imgWidth});
  $('.caption-style-1').css({width: imgWidth});
  $('.blur').css({width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight});
});
```

```css
.container-a1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.caption-style-1{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
 }

 .caption-style-1 li{
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .caption-style-1 li:hover .caption{
  opacity: 1;

 }


 .caption-style-1 img{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 4;
 }


 .caption-style-1 .caption{
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 0.45s ease-in-out;

 }
 .caption-style-1 .blur{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
    position: absolute;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
 }

 .caption-style-1 .caption-text h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
 }
 .caption-style-1 .caption-text{
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  top:100px;
 }

.imagen {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-a1">
  <ul class="caption-style-1">
   <li>
    <img class="imagen" src="http://uploads5.wikiart.org/images/claude-monet/the-summer-poppy-field.jpg"/" alt="">
    <div class="caption">
     <div class="blur"></div>
     <div class="caption-text">
      <h1>Amazing Caption</h1>
      <p>Whatever It Is - Always Awesome</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```